# Вопрос про словосочетания

Tags: словосочетания

В словосочетаниях типа согласования может ли зависимое слово быть причастием?
Пример:
`Слова определяющие(Какой тип? Какое главное и зависимое слово?)`

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Да, причастие может быть **зависимым словом** в словосочетании, его грамматическая форма такая же, как у прилагательного. Причастие согласуется с существительным в **роде, числе и падеже.**

**Пример** с причастием: *Один из **определяющих вопросов** при изучении токопереноса в диэлектриках — вопрос о типе контакта металл — кристалл.*

Причастие совмещает постоянные признаки **глагола** (залог, вид, возвратность, время) и непостоянные признаки **прилагательного** (род, число, падеж), которые выражаются с помощью окончаний.

Причастие отвечает на вопрос ***какой***?

**[Материалы в Интернете](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8%2C,%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%3A%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC)**

***Согласование** — такой вид связи, при котором главное слово требует, чтобы зависимое принимало те же грамматические формы в которых оно само употреблено. Такая связь возникает между определяемым и определением, то есть между существительным и прилагательным, а также **другими частями речи**, которые могут выступать в функции прилагательного: **причастием**, порядковым числительным, местоимением-прилагательным. Зависимое слово во всех этих случаях стоит перед главным, начавшийся процесс, первые успехи, наши огорчения.*

Answer (score 0):

**Интересный материал о названии "причастие"**

Итак, причастием называют форму **глагола**, но его  грамматическая форма совпадает с формой **прилагательного**. Интересный парадокс!  Так к чему же в большей степени «причастно  причастие»?

**[Из статьи](https://%D0%98%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA,%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0,%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%81%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE.%20%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81!%20%20%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BA%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%C2%AB%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%C2%BB?%20%20%D0%98%D0%B7%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B8%20%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%20%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%98%D0%95%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5?%20%D0%A1%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B,%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B,%20%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%81%20%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20participium%20(%D1%81%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC).%20Pars,%20partis%20%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%E2%80%93%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C,%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5.%20(%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8.)%20%D0%90%20%D1%81%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B,%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%E2%80%93%20%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%22%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE,%20%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5.%20(%D0%92%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85%20%D1%83%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5.)%20%D0%92%2016%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B%20%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA,%20%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0.%20%D0%92%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD,%20%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5,%20%20%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83.%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C,%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%2016%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%20%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B8%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE,%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%20-%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%20(%D1%81%20%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)%20%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B6%D0%B5,%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5.)** **Почему часть речи ПРИЧАСТИЕ имеет такое название?**

С одной стороны, это обозначение части речи или глагольной формы, а именно калька с латинского ***participium*** (с таким же значением). ***Pars, partis*** по-латински – часть, вот переводчики и подобрали соответствующий славянский вариант. (Такими же кальками являются и многие другие грамматические термины.) А с другой стороны, причастие – "православное" слово, а точнее церковнославянское. (В священных текстах у него тоже терминологическое значение.)

В XVI веке на Руси появляются сначала переводы **античных грамматик**, а потом собственные попытки составить описание языка. В отличие от ученых более поздних времен, средневековые монахи предпочитали термины не заимствовать в большом количестве,  а **переделывать по-своему**.

Важно учесть, что в XVI веке язык книжный и язык разговорный **различались** значительно, как два разных языка Поэтому термины-кальки (с латинского и греческого)  **конструировались** так же, как и переводы слов из Священного писания столетиями ранее.